# Why am I not able to read the doument name in spring for mongodb?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a ThreadLocale in which i am setting some value which i want to read while creating the mongo document..

```
        @Service
        public class DocumentContext {

        private ThreadLocal<String> currentValue = new ThreadLocal<>();

        public void setName(String documentName) {
            currentValue.set(documentName);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return currentValue.get();
        }

    }
```

I am using this to set the value in my filter:

```
@Autowired
    private DocumentContext docContext;

@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final String col= "value1";         
        docContext.setCurrentValue(col);            
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        docContext.setCurrentValue(null);
    }
```

Now i have my POJO class in which i am using like this:

```
@Data
@Document(collection="doc.#{docContext.getName()}.tableName")
class Entity{

}
```

But, in the mongo i am getting the collection name as :

> `doc..tablename`

I was expecting :

> `doc.value1.tablename`

Please suggest am i missing something.

Comment: In your filter you're saying `docContext.setCurrentTenant(col);` but shouldn't it be `setName(col);`? Or is that just a typo in the question.

Comment: @Gregg Sorry it's a typo